# Cocoa how to make the window 3D transform effect for a mac app?

Tags: cocoa, 3d, window

Hey all, I am not familiar to the cocoa 3D transform, I wanna to make a window do a cube transform when a toolbar button clicked in my mac app. but what I found in the Apple Reference Doc just can make a view do the cube transform, but how about the window?

Answer (score 0):

This is not pretty, but you might want to take a look at [this](http://karanmisra.com/journal/2008/08/nswindow-and-animation.html) blog post.  Basically, looks like you're going to want to render your NSWindow into another NSWindow that pretends to be the main window, use that for animations, and then dispose of it once the animation is done.  There's a code sample on there as well.